# Lowest cost path of a graph

Tags: graph, graph-traversal, floyd-warshall

I am working on a problem which drills down to this:

> There is a connected undirected graph. I need to visit all the nodes
>   without visiting a node more than once. I can start and end at any
>   arbitrary node.

How can I go about this? Shall I apply algorithm like `Floyd-Warshall` to all start nodes possible or is there a better way to do?

Thanks.

Comment: is it something similar to TSP ? Travelling Sales person ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with an undirected graph being called strongly connected.  Do you mean completely connected, or do you just mean connected?  I'm assuming that you don't mean completely connected, otherwise your problem would be trivial.

Comment: Sorry. It's a connected graph.

Answer (score 4):

A path that visits every node once and only once is called a **Hamiltonian Path**. The problem of finding a Hamiltonian Path is called [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem).

First of all, this problem is NP-Complete. An algorithm whose run time is proportional to at most a polynomial of input size is called a polynomial algorithm. For example, most sorting algorithms require O(N logN) time, which is less than N^2, which makes it polynomial.

For NP-complete problems there is no known polynomial time algorithm. Although no one could prove it yet, most probably there is no polynomial time algorithm for NP-complete problems. It means:

1. the run time of any algorithm you will come up with will be proportional to an exponential function of input size. (i.e. if it solve the problem with 40 nodes in an hour, it will require 2 hours for 41 nodes, 4 hours for 42 nodes, ..) Which is very bad news.
2. The algorithm you will come up with will not be fundamentally much faster than one that proceeds with try and error.

If your input size is small, start with a simple backtracking algorithm. If you need to do better, a google search with terms like "hamiltonian path", "longest path" may provide an answer. Ultimately you will have to lower your expectations, (for example settle with an approximation instead of an optimal solution) if your input is large.